# fullCalendar generate repeating events with unique id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

So, what I am working on is a calendar where there are empty events, and when the user clicks, he adds his "team" to the event. After that, there will be confirm dialog with POST request to the database. So basically on the next occasion the user will pull the data from the server, and javascript is going to fill the events with provided data.

For testing purposes I've manually created the events repeating 6 days in a week using `dow: []` property.

My aim is to not overload the database with empty events. I want to put them in the record only if there exists a team that user defined.

My problem is that the event is repeating itself, but it shares the id , and the changes apply to the all of it's instances repeating every day.

To make it easy to you to visualize what I'm talking about here is my visual part that is relevant:

[image: If I update event.team1 = 'some team' to the event at 8:00 ,pon. 18.5, it will apply to all the events later. i.e. uto,sri,čet....]

So, I need an advice on how to update event combining properties `id` and `start`, or if you have different solution in mind.

Comment: If I understand maybe you have to create all events in database without teams name, like in your image, and on post success update the events. With this flow you can use always `eventSources` fullcalendar method to get the events.